# The functor category Funct(R-Mod, S-Mod)

Tags: ct.category-theory, modules

Can you name some properties of the functor category Funct(R-Mod,S-Mod), where R,S are associative rings with unit?

EDIT:
I am sorry for the lack of precision of my (first in MO) question. I was thinking in a sort of Yoneda's Lemma for functors $F\colon R\mbox{-Mod}\to S\mbox{-Mod}$, maybe using tensorizing functors $h_U$ to describe $Nat(h_U,F)$.

Comment: I think it might that your question has been downvoted because it comes off as vague. But I for instance am very ignorant about this category and only recently started reading about Morita theory. So answers would be nice :)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask - **what** properties? Is it very like a whale?

Comment: Here is a definite question you might ask: One knows their is a "set"(?) map $ring(S,R)\rightarrow Fun(R-mod,S-mod)$. Other than elements in the image of this map, what else is there? What is a concrete example something not in this image? What are some conditions on $R$ and $S$ for this map to be an isomorphism? Answers to these questions might shed some light on the properties of the category. 

Comment: Thank you Spice-the-Bird for this point of view. I think that it may be connected with Morita theory (as Yosemite-Sam mentioned), in the sense that equivalence functors are special ones in Funct(R-Mod,S-Mod), and I believe they may not be in the image of this map, for example two rings not connected by an homomorphism, may be Morita  equivalent.

Comment: In Morita theory, you should consider the category of R-S bimodules. Tensoring with a bimodule gives all colimit preserving functors and so in particular all equivalences. Bimodules form a nice abelian category. 

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, these are the adjoint functors, and I think they form an interesting subclass of the functor category.

Comment: -1 since still there is no precise question at all. 

Comment: Voting to close.  Cocontinuous functors are precisely bimodules, but then this question is too elementary for MO.  Otherwise it is unclear what the OP actually wants and it is impossible to guess since he gives no context for his question.

Comment: The edited version is a bit more precise, but still not very clear. There is a general Yoneda lemma for enriched categories, you can find it in Kelly's book and of course at the nlab. For example, a representable functor $\mathrm{Mod}(R) \to \mathrm{Mod}(S)$ is the same as an $R$-module which is also a $S$-comodule, and for these Yoneda's lemma works as usual.